# Unable to override CSS pseudo element :before

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have couple of unordered list items which specify the rule for password and use the font awesome to display an icon in front of all list items, when i click on the button i have javascript call that check if rule satisfy or not, based on the condition i have to change the font awesome icon , see below code

```
 li {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
    li:before {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        content: "\f056";
        color: dimgray;
    }

    .myClass{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        font-family: FontAwesome !important;
        content: "\f058" !important;
        color: forestgreen;
    }
```

to override `li:before` i have the fallowing code

```
$("#limsg").addClass("myClass");
```

what should i be doing to get different font awesome icon at runtime?

Comment: `::before` is a pseudo-*element*, not a pseudo-class. If you want to change it you need to select *it* and set new values.

Comment: Use `.myClass:before { ... }`

Comment: If i have 10 rules and two of them pass and rest fail and if pass and fail to be distinguished with different icons how should i do it?? can you point me to any url??

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but to override li:before, you need myClass:before

```
 .myClass:before{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-family: FontAwesome !important;
    content: "\f058" !important;
    color: forestgreen;
}
```

you can check the plunkr for details.
https://plnkr.co/S41mrN